how do i manipulate my javascript based automation framework to mouse over i.e the pointer to hover over a menu item?
I am currently experimenting with the automation UI test framework called Nightwatch.js.
I am trying to get my test to manipulate the mouse to hover over a menu item with submenus.
It keeps failing.
I want to get it to look like this in the below screenshot:
what i want my automation script to do so that it can click on one of the submenus
Please can anybody provide recommendations or help?
The below code is my test scripts.
describe('Test for all things on the portal ui', function(){
    it('Test navigation to the claims portal ui', function(browser){
        let shared = browser.page.commonStuff();

        shared
            .navigate()
            .login()

        let portals = browser.page.portalsPage();
        portals.expect.section('@menu').to.be.visible;

        let menuSection = portals.section.menu;

        menuSection.perform(function() {
            const actions = this.actions({async: true});


            return actions
            .mouse()
            .move(300,{origin : element('@menu')},94,45)
            .mouse()
            .pause(10000);
            
        })

       
        menuSection.expect.element('@admin').to.be.visible;
        menuSection.expect.element('@claims').to.be.visible;

        menuSection.click('@claims');
        
        
        browser.end();
          

    });
});

The execution log produces this message:
PS C:\nmauto\bitbucketProject> npx nightwatch test/portalsTest.js


[Test for all things on the portal ui] Test Suite
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
ℹ Connected to GeckoDriver on port 4444 (5142ms).
  Using: firefox (132.0.1) on WINDOWS.


  Running Test navigation to the claims portal ui:
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  ℹ Loaded url https://test.natmed.mobi in 1280ms
  √ Element <body> was visible after 114 milliseconds.
  √ Expected element @menu <#PortalsIndex> to be visible (1169ms)
12 Nov 08:42:19  ✖ TypeError
   Error while running "perform" command: [TypeError] actions.mouse(...).move(...).mouse is not a function
      - writing an ES6 async test case? - keep in mind that commands return a Promise; 
      - writing unit tests? - make sure to specify "unit_tests_mode=true" in your config.

    Error location:
    C:\nmauto\bitbucketProject\test\portalsTest.js:21
    ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
     19 |             .mouse()
     20 |             .move(300,{origin : element('@menu')},94,45)
     21 |             .mouse() 
     22 |             .pause(10000);
     23 |
    ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

    Stack Trace :
    at NightwatchAPI.<anonymous> (C:\nmauto\bitbucketProject\test\portalsTest.js:21:14)
    at Object.apply (C:\nmauto\bitbucketProject\node_modules\nightwatch\lib\api\_loaders\_base-loader.js:411:29)
    at CommandInstance.runCallback (C:\nmauto\bitbucketProject\node_modules\nightwatch\lib\api\client-commands\perform.js:122:17)
    at CommandInstance.command (C:\nmauto\bitbucketProject\node_modules\nightwatch\lib\api\client-commands\perform.js:74:27)
    at C:\nmauto\bitbucketProject\node_modules\nightwatch\lib\api\_loaders\command.js:182:29
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)


  FAILED: 1 assertions failed and  2 passed (14.877s)

───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

  ️TEST FAILURE (22.681s):
   - 1 assertions failed; 2 passed

   × 1) portalsTest

   – Test navigation to the claims portal ui (14.877s)

   → TypeError
   Error while running "perform" command: [TypeError] actions.mouse(...).move(...).mouse is not a function

    Error location:
    C:\nmauto\bitbucketProject\test\portalsTest.js:21
    ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
     19 |             .mouse()
     20 |             .move(300,{origin : element('@menu')},94,45)
     21 |             .mouse() 
     22 |             .pause(10000);
     23 |
    ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

